# Location Search Similar to Groupon

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to implement location search similar to Groupon Location Search. I know about [google places api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) and have gone through it, but i am unable to implement the search only for city and state code ( as Groupon location search do). Also i want to dropdown menu same as groupon do. I know, I can change the css of google location dropdown, but if there is some service other than google how can I do it for.

Desperately looking for help.

Thanks

Comment: what i have done yet http://jsfiddle.net/AdmanBar/4mVyw/#&togetherjs=RyKtlQF1u5

Answer (score 0):

One possible datasource for locations (cities/countries) is GeoNames.org

You can either download their entire database, install and use it in your web application (http://www.geonames.org/export/) or access their web services (an overview of the available services can be found here: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html).

As for the dropdown/typeahead UI, check out Angular Bootstrap (requires AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap's CSS, http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or jQuery UI's AutoComplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).